# Original Number of verses in Samaveda

Tags: rig-veda, sama-veda

Wikipedia says that Samveda has 1875 verses of which only 75 are its own and others are from Rigveda. Then how does Samveda has a 600+ verse Chhandogya Upanishad if only 75 are its own?

Comment: Presumably, the lines from the Chandogya Upanishad are being counted separately and not included in the tally.

Comment: When they count the number of mantras in X Veda then they just count the number of mantras in the Samhita only.